# The test not run in other activity robotium

Tags: robotium, android-testing

I'm using robotium to test an application. In my test class have 2 tests:

```
public class MainActivityTestAll extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

private Solo solo;
private static TestItem item;
private boolean isTimeOut;
private ArrayList<Button> arrButton;

private static final String USER_NAME = "varick";
private static final String PASSWORD = "123456";
private static final String BTN_DISMISS = "Dismiss";
private static final String BTN_OK = "OK";
private static final String BTN_TRYAGAIN = "Try Again";
private static final String BTN_CANCEL = "Cancel";
private static final String BTN_GETSTARTED = "Get Started";
private static final String BTN_EXIT = "Exit";

private static EditText edtName, edtPass;
private View inflaterView;

private Button btnLight, btnSwitch, btnOutlet;

public MainActivityTestAll(String name) {
    super(MainActivity.class);
    setName(name);
}

public void setUp() throws Exception {
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    edtName = (EditText) solo.getView(R.id.edittext_userName);
    edtPass = (EditText) solo.getView(R.id.edittext_passWord);
    LayoutInflater i = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(
        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflaterView = i.inflate(R.layout.consumer_welcome, null);
    isTimeOut = true;
    item = new TestItem();
}


@MediumTest
public void test1_DoorLock_Click() throws Exception {

    Login();

    View view = (View) solo.getView(R.id.fragment_holder);
    solo.waitForView(view);
    solo.clickOnView(view);
    solo.waitForActivity(ConsumerSystemMapDetailPhone.class.getName());

    btnLight = (Button) solo.getView(R.id.btnLight);
    btnSwitch = (Button) solo.getView(R.id.btnSwitch);
    btnOutlet = (Button) solo.getView(R.id.btnOutlet);

    assertNotNull(btnLight);
    assertNotNull(btnSwitch);
    assertNotNull(btnOutlet);

    solo.clickOnView(btnLight);
    solo.clickOnView(btnSwitch);
    solo.clickOnView(btnOutlet);

    solo.sleep(2000);

    arrButton = solo.getCurrentViews(Button.class,
        solo.getView(R.id.consumerzoom_main_container));

    assertTrue("DoorLock button had not active", clickonDoorlock(arrButton.get(0)));
}


@MediumTest
public void test2_Switch_Click() throws Exception{

    /*
    btnLight = (Button) solo.getView(R.id.btnLight);
    btnOutlet = (Button) solo.getView(R.id.btnOutlet);
    assertNotNull(btnLight);
    assertNotNull(btnOutlet);

    solo.clickOnView(btnLight);
    solo.clickOnView(btnOutlet);
    */

    btnSwitch = (Button) solo.getView(R.id.btnSwitch);
    assertNotNull(btnSwitch);
    solo.clickOnView(btnSwitch);
    solo.sleep(2000);

    clickonSpinner(1, 3);
    solo.sleep(1000);

    arrButton = solo.getCurrentViews(Button.class, solo.getView(R.id.consumerzoom_main_container));
    clickonSwitch(arrButton.get(0), true, item.getbtnLevel2());

    clickonSpinner(0, 1);
    clickonSpinner(1, 4);
    solo.sleep(1000);

    arrButton = solo.getCurrentViews(Button.class, solo.getView(R.id.consumerzoom_main_container));
    clickonSwitchInfortop(arrButton.get(0), false, item.getbtnParentLevel8(), item.getbtnLevel3());
    exitApp();
}
```

My problem is after test1 finish the test2 do nothing. It still running but do nothing. When I put the code from test2 into test1 it run ok.

I'm not sure what's wrong here but I guess the reason is because the test2 doesn't start from MainActivity.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you are missing tearDown method:

```
@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
}
```

Comment: I think that's not problem. I also try with tearDown() but it doesn't work.